# Crystal Reports in Visual Studio 2010 dao error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, crystal-reports, dao

I had an image, but I don't have enough reputation to post it.  The error is as follows:

**Database Connector Error: 'DAO Error Code: 0xbe4**
**Source: DAO.Fields**
**Description: 'P:\db\Name.mdb' is not a valid path.  Make sure that the**
**path name is spelled correctly and that you are connected to the server**
**on which the file resides**

I have been tasked with converting a good many Crystal Reports to SSRS.  Unfortunately, I can not get the path of my first report to change to where it is now located on my computer.  I have been trying to get into the code, but this error pops up when I try to look at the SQL, when I try to preview the main report, and when I try to verify the database.

We have copied this .rpt and the access database file directly from the company we are doing this for, but it will not work.  I can't even find this path ANYWHERE I've looked or with the find function, and when I look at the properties the correct path is there.  I don't understand what is wrong.

I do know that CR has a lot of issues, especially moving around on machines, but I've never dealt with anything like this before.

Any help to resolve this error so I can begin working on these reports would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you create a mapped drive on your system called `P:` to point to where the database file is on your computer (in a directory called `db`)?

Answer (score -1):

Just Google "Crystal Reports to SSRS" and you will find solution to convert Crystal to SSRS automatically.

If you like to have a try, you may send your report to support@crystalmigration.com

Most Crystal Reports can be perfectly automatically converted to SSRS.